# Error using Django Facebook

Tags: django, django-facebook

I am trying to use Django Facebook to register users in my app.
Right now I am in local develoment and after giving persmissions to the app in Facebook and following all indications in readthedocs, I get the next error:

Please specify a Facebook app id and ensure the context processor is enabled

Django version: 1.8
Python version: 3.8

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was an error django-facebook code, which has been fixed. Make sure you are using django-facebook 6.0.4 or later. Even if the latest model is not yet shipped you can get it by doing pip install git+git://github.com/tschellenbach/Django-facebook.git